# ある文字列とある文字列を辞書順での順序を判定したい

Tags: sh

ある文字列とある文字列が、辞書順で大きいのか小さいのかを判定したいです。
どうしたら実現できるでしょうか。

知っていること: bash では `[[ $str1 < $str2 ]]` で判定できるのは知っているのですが、
これは bash の拡張構文であると思っていて、 `sh` ではどう行うのだろうと疑問に思っているので、質問しています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort`のcheckオプションとか

```
( echo "$str1"; echo "$str2" ) | sort -C
```

EDIT: strcmp.sh

同じ文字列の場合はもちろん`=`が使えるので、移植性考えながら`strcmp`モドキを作るならこんな感じでしょうか。

```
#!/bin/sh

[ -z ${1+x} ] && exit 1
[ -z ${2+x} ] && exit 1
[ "$1" = "$2" ] && printf "%d\n" 0 && exit 0
printf "%s\n%s\n" "$1" "$2" | sort -C \
    && printf "%d\n" -1 \
    || printf "%d\n" 1
```

Comment: posix compliant ですね。

Comment: @YukiInoue  `$str1` と `$str2` が同じ文字列の場合、exit status が 0 になりますが(expr コマンドと結果が異なる)、問題ありませんか？

Comment: @metropolis そこは、確かに。個人的には、辞書順での文字列比較がやりたかったことで、それが確かに簡潔にできそうだったので accept しました。 `<=` ではなく、 `<` であることに特にこだわりはなかったのですが、もし厳密に `<` が使いたい場合には、 expr の方がいいのかもしれないです。

Comment: 同じ文字列の比較は標準の`test`で可能です。回答の内容を変更しました。

Answer (score 2):

(POSIX) sh の組み込み関数には、文字列の大小比較ができるものは存在しないので、そのような場合、一般的には `expr` コマンドを使います。

```
expr "$str1" "<" "$str2" > /dev/null
```

しかし組み込み関数ではないために、上記のように `<` や `>` をいちいちクォートするかエスケープしなければならなく、あまり見た目がよろしくないので、あまり積極的には使われないと思います。

文字列比較が必要になった時点で、sed, AWK, Perl, Python, Ruby といったスクリプト言語を使うケースが多いと思います。

Comment: こちら、`expr "$str1" "<" "$str2" > /dev/null` ではないでしょうか？(`[`, `]` が余計 )

Comment: @metropolis ご指摘ありがとうございました。ご指摘のとおり修正しました。